# Raspberry pi UPS with dual power supply

Tags: power-supply, ups

I'm now building a project with a raspberry pi, and [GPS module](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwi3ppWO_OnTAhXFK1AKHW0NABAQFghGMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwiki.dragino.com%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DLora%2FGPS_HAT&usg=AFQjCNGNwQgmRADDn30Y7HVb44MY0aFrHQ&sig2=10TvLhnt2S_46J-Rs7lIwg), a [touchscreen](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjU3puh_OnTAhUBZ1AKHR6XCBEQFghAMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.waveshare.com%2Fwiki%2F7inch_HDMI_LCD_(B)&usg=AFQjCNFxZU3y1z1o01HVa8F8c4dvkdjCng&sig2=XaxFnqwhBtKICbiNzk3k0A) and a [UPS](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjrvbSG_OnTAhUIY1AKHeKzCXAQFggqMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.raspberrypiwiki.com%2Findex.php%2FRaspi_UPS_HAT_Board&usg=AFQjCNFns1IbZFwSGz1HMrmPHgT9Je-aOA&sig2=IvKt6wN4VZIjcVd2P1B-Xg).

Now, when I use the UPS, I need to supply power from the UPS to the pi. However, the soyrce o the power will come from a [car-power-supply](https://cfshopeeph-a.akamaihd.net/file/cdebefe07131c2ee9327ebac1c7d372e). Now, I have a maximum current of 2.4 Amps, wich doens't cover the components current request enough.

Now my question is, IF I would give power to the UPS AND to the pi simultaneously, would this harm any component? Will I be able to get 4.8 Amps as maximum current instead of the 2.4 Amps?

Comment: I've used the RPi official 7" touchscreen and RPi3, and plugged two 2.4 amp power inputs in before (keep in mind these are IQ ports and automatically adjust), and it worked fine.  However, I don't know if your situation is different, and I'm not guaranteeing anything, just sharing my experience.

Comment: Hi, well the power led of my pi starts to flicker wich indicates that the pi has a low power input.

Comment: Yeah, I received I warning with one power input as well.  If your power supply is good and doesn't waver, you should be fine, the Pi supports an Amperage range as low as 2.1 (that's off the top of my head, might not be right)

Comment: Well, the pi works just fine with the touchscreen, but I want to give it enough juce so it can work with a higher amount of addons (hats)